# How can I make a file open with Windows startup?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word

I have a MS Word file that I use to plan me week. I want the file to open with Windows startup so I don't forget to look at it. I know that I can put programs in startup but I don't know how can I make it for specific file.

Comment: Just a note for others who may find this. You do not want to use the Word Startup folder for this. It has a different purpose and will never open a file for editing. My page on that startup folder: https://addbalance.com/word/startup.htm#PageStart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a file run automatically on login, create a
desktop shortcut to the file and move it into the Startup group at:

```
C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Comment: Small addon, easiest way to reach the above path, in explorer, click the addresbar so you can type in it, then type: `shell:startup` and press enter, and you'll get to the location you want to go to.